# webpack: should NPM be run on prod servers?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I added webpack to a project and a team member asked me if I committed the compiled folders (`dist`).  I said no and he said it should be commited since he doesn't want NPM running on the production server.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of webpack?

Answer (score 2):

No, development tools should not be used on production.

On production use any static server, where you serve your dist files!